# Как отправить id элемента в объект?

Tags: javascript

Задача: Есть три шага в форме, после выбора одного из элементов выбранный шаг, а следующий появляется. По клику на элемент нужно отправить его id в объект registration, как это сделать?

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var steps = document.querySelectorAll('.master-change, .service-change, .date-block');

// Скрываем все шаги при загрузке страницы

window.onload = function() {
  steps.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (index > 0) {
      element.classList.add('hide');
    }
  });
};

//Переход по шагам

var choiseElement = document.querySelectorAll('.master-list, .service-list'); // Выбираем элементы с которых отлавливаем клик

choiseElement.forEach((element, index) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextStep(element, index); // Вешаем событие на каждый из них
  }, false);
});

var registration = {
  masterName: '',
  serviceType: '',
  time: ''
};

function nextStep(el, index) {
  steps[index].classList.toggle('hide'); // После клика элемент исчезает
  steps[index + 1].classList.toggle('hide'); // А идущий за ним появляется
}

const submit = document.querySelector('.btn-submit');

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault(); // Отменяем действие по умолчанию

  request.open('GET', './scripts/info.json', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', './scripts/info.json; charset=UTF-8');

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      // alert(request.responseText);
    } else {
      console.log(request.status + ' ' + request.statusText);
    }
  }

  request.send();

  console.log(registration);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main class="pageBody">
  <div class="index">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="form-block">
        <form class="form-order" name="form-order">
          <div class="from-order__step from-order__step-1 master-change">
            <div class="master-list">
              <div class="master-list__item" id="master_1"><img class="master-list__photo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" width="64px" height="64px" alt="Master photo">
                <div class="master-name" id="master_1" href="#">Master name</div>
              </div>
              <div class="master-list__item" id="master_2"><img class="master-list__photo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" width="64px" height="64px" alt="Master photo">
                <div class="master-name" id="master_2" href="#">Master name</div>
              </div>
              <div class="master-list__item" id="master_3"><img class="master-list__photo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64" width="64x" height="64px" alt="Master photo">
                <div class="master-name" id="master_3" href="#">Master name</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="from-order__step from-order__step-2 service-change hide">
            <div class="service-list">
              <div class="service-list__item" id="service_1">
                <h3 class="service__item__name">Service name </h3>
                <p class="service__item__description">Service description Service description Service description Service description</p><span class="service__price">999 rub</span><span class="service__time">14:44</span>
              </div>
              <div class="service-list__item" id="service_2">
                <h3 class="service__item__name">Service name </h3>
                <p class="service__item__description">Service description Service description Service description Service description</p><span class="service__price">999 rub</span><span class="service__time">14:44</span>
              </div>
              <div class="service-list__item" id="service_3">
                <h3 class="service__item__name">Service name </h3>
                <p class="service__item__description">Service description Service description Service description Service description</p><span class="service__price">999 rub</span><span class="service__time">14:44</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="from-order__step from-order__step-3 date-block hide">
            <div class="date-block__calendar">
              <div class="date-block__time">
                <select class="date-block__time">
                      <option>10:00</option>
                      <option>11:00</option>
                      <option>12:00</option>
                      <option>13:00</option>
                      <option>14:00</option>
                      <option>15:00</option>
                      <option>16:00</option>
                      <option>17:00</option>
                      <option>18:00</option>
                      <option>19:00</option>
                      <option>20:00</option>
                    </select>
              </div>
              <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit">Отправить</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: `отправить его id в объект registration` что ето значит ? просто взять ИД елемента и запихнуть его в обьект ?

Comment: Нужно получить следующее 

registration {
    masterName : masterID,
   serviceType: serviceID
}

Comment: откуда получить ?

Comment: Получить от элемента по которому кликнули, в с .master-list__item к примеру

Comment: чет я не могу понять что вам надо, на при клику на елемент получить ид очень просто, как-то так : `element.id`

Comment: Логика такая: пользователь кликает на элемент ->  id элемента записывается в объект -> пользователь переходит к следующему шагу

Comment: `element.addEventListener('click', function(){console.log(this.id);}); `  ???

Comment: проверка вывода айди

Comment: ну так в чем проблема взять этот айди и записать в обьект ?

Comment: я думаю что если бы проблемы не было я бы здесь не сидел